# Nav dropdown icon jumping to new line

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4 and `dropdown-toggle:after` to list out siblings as wordpress menu.  Cant get the carrot to stay on the same line as text on small screens.

[image]

Code example:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle article-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
  <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title d-inline-block">', '</h1>' ); ?> 
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-articles sibling-dropdown">
    <?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Code example link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4bf9sq2g/

Comment: somehow the jsfiddle example doesn't work for me, so could try it in your example

Answer (score 1):

Adding this css property to the dropdown-toggle class helped me:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```